# Merge Two text files line by line using batch script

Tags: file, text, batch-file, scripting, merge

I have 2 text files; A.txt and B.txt and I want to merge them to make C.txt using a batch script.

However (here's the tricky part) I wish to do it so each line from A.txt is appended with a space then the first line from B.txt then a new line with the first line from A and the second from B and so on until the end of B is reached and then we start with the second line of A.

I know I haven't worded this well so here's an example:

A.txt;

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

B.txt;

```
Z
Y
X
W
V
T
R
```

So C.txt would have;

```
1 Z
1 Y
1 X
1 W
1 V
1 T
1 R
2 Z
2 Y
```

etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (a.txt) do (
    for /f "delims=" %%b in (b.txt) do (
        >>c.txt echo %%a %%b
    )
)
```

Comment: +1 It is funny that what the OP calls "the tricky part" is precisely the requirement that makes this solution so simple! **;-)**

Comment: Thanks - works perfectly! This was so much simpler than I thought it would be! I'm obviously out of touch :/

Comment: foxidrive, this is a nice loop, what if one would like, with the same files given as example:

1 a
2 b 
3 c 
...

instead of what it is now:

1 a
1 b
1 c
1 d
1 e
2 a
2 b
2 c