# Batch FOR LOOP a line of text from each file and ECHO both lines

Tags: loops, batch-file, merge

OS: Windows 7

I need to output two lines; one from each text file, side by side. Similar to what has been shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097036/merge-two-text-files-line-by-line-using-batch-script).

A.txt;

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

B.txt;

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

So I would like to echo;

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this squirrled away which gives you a technique to solve that.

```
@echo off
del file1.txt 2>nul
del file2.txt 2>nul

for %%a in (A B C D) do echo %%a>>file2.txt
for %%a in (1 2 3 4) do echo %%a>>file1.txt

@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
< file2.txt (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
      set file2Line=
      set /P file2Line=
      set "file1Line=%%a"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion   
      echo(!file1Line! !file2Line!
      endlocal
   )
)
pause

del file1.txt 2>nul
del file2.txt 2>nul
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Wow! It took me more than 10 minutes to check out **how** you did the trick! Just one annotation: to write the output to a file, edit the line just above `pause` to `)>newfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` processing a batch file is the worst choice for such a text files merging task as it is designed for executing commands and executables and not for processing text files.

But this text lines merging task can be done with a batch file if the files two merge are not too large and the lines are not too long which means the line output by command **ECHO** must have less than 8192 characters not counting the newline characters carriage return and line-feed.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FileA=%~dp0A.txt"
set "FileB=%~dp0B.txt"
set "ResultsFile=%~dp0Merged AB.txt"
if not exist "%FileA%" echo ERROR: Missing file: "%FileA%"& exit /B
if not exist "%FileB%" echo ERROR: Missing file: "%FileB%"& exit /B
set "FileALinesCount=0"
set "FileBLinesCount=0"
for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set Line 2^>nul') do set "%%I="
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /N "^" "%FileA%"') do for /F delims^=:^ eol^= %%J in ("%%I") do set "LineA%%J=%%I" & set "FileALinesCount=%%J"
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /N "^" "%FileB%"') do for /F delims^=:^ eol^= %%J in ("%%I") do set "LineB%%J=%%I" & set "FileBLinesCount=%%J"
if %FileALinesCount% GEQ %FileBLinesCount% (set "LinesCount=%FileALinesCount%") else set "LinesCount=%FileBLinesCount%"
if %LinesCount% == 0 del "%ResultsFile%" 2>nul & exit /B
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /L %%I in (1,1,%LinesCount%) do (
    if defined LineA%%I (
        if defined LineB%%I (
            echo(!LineA%%I:*:=! !LineB%%I:*:=!
        ) else echo(!LineA%%I:*:=!
    ) else echo(!LineB%%I:*:=!
))>"%ResultsFile%"
endlocal
endlocal
```

This batch file first defines the required execution environment by disabling command echo mode, enabling command extensions and disabling delayed environment variable expansion.

Next is checked if the files `A.txt` and `B.txt` exist both in the directory of the batch file otherwise an error message is output and the batch file processing ends.

The first **FOR** loop deletes all environment variables which are by chance already defined with a name starting with `Line`.

The second **FOR** loop runs one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the **FINDSTR** command line appended as additional arguments which just outputs all lines with line number and colon of file `A.txt`. The output lines are captured by **FOR** and assigned completely to loop variable `I`. For each line one more **FOR** is used to get the line number left to the colon and define next an environment variable with name `LineA` and the line number appended with the entire line output by **FINDSTR** assigned as value. The current line number is additionally assigned to the environment variable `FileALinesCount`.

The third **FOR** loop does the same for all lines in file `B.txt`.

The number of lines of each file could be different. For that reason the **IF** condition finds out what is the greatest lines count value and assigns it to the environment variable `LinesCount`.

The results file is deleted on already existing (from a previous execution of the batch file) on file `A.txt` and `B.txt` both exist, but are both empty files.

Next one more **FOR** loop is used now in an environment with enabled delayed environment variable expansion to output the lines from the two files merged together on one line with using a space character between them. In case of file `A.txt` has more lines than file `B.txt`, then just the line of file `A.txt` is output if there is no more line from file `B.txt`. In case of file `B.txt` has more lines than file `A.txt`, then just the line of file `B.txt` is output if there is no more line from file `A.txt`. The output lines are written into the results files as defined at top of the batch file. The line number and the colon added by **FINDSTR** on output of all lines to standard output stream of background command process are removed during the output of the lines by using a string substitution.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file path
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also: [How to read and print contents of text file line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579256/3074564)

---

Some additional information about the line length limitations can be read on the Microsoft documentation pages:

- [Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables)
- [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation)

The argument string of command **SET** or command **ECHO** cannot have more than 8191 characters.

In the batch file code above the argument string of command **SET** is everything after `set` and the space character separating the command from its argument, i.e. the quotation mark `"`, the variable name, the equal sign `=`, the string value and once again the quotation mark `"`.

The argument string of command **ECHO** is in the batch file everything after the command `echo` and left parenthesis `(` used as separator instead of a space character to output correct also an empty line or a line starting with `/?`.

Here is an example to demonstrate the command line argument(s) string length limitation of 8191 characters.

There is a batch file `LengthTest.cmd` with the following command lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "InputFile=%~dp0Length Test Input.txt"
if not exist "%InputFile%" exit /B
set "OutputFile=%~dp0Length Test Output"
del "%OutputFile% *.txt" 2>nul
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo(%%I
    set "Line=%%I"
    echo(!Line!
))>"%OutputFile% 1_1.txt"
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo(%%I
    set Line=%%I
    echo(!Line!
))>"%OutputFile% 2_1.txt"
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo(%%I
    set L=%%I
    echo(!L!
))>"%OutputFile% 3_1.txt"
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo(%%I
    set L=%%I
    echo(!L! !L!
))>"%OutputFile% 4_1.txt"
(for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo(%%I
))>"%OutputFile% 5_1.txt"
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo(%%I>>"%OutputFile% 1_2.txt"
    set "Line=%%I"
    echo(!Line!>>"%OutputFile% 1_2.txt"
)
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo(%%I>>"%OutputFile% 2_2.txt"
    set Line=%%I
    echo(!Line!>>"%OutputFile% 2_2.txt"
)
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo(%%I>>"%OutputFile% 3_2.txt"
    set L=%%I
    echo(!L!>>"%OutputFile% 3_2.txt"
)
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo(%%I>>"%OutputFile% 4_2.txt"
    set L=%%I
    echo(!L! !L!>>"%OutputFile% 4_2.txt"
)
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("%InputFile%") do (
    echo(%%I>>"%OutputFile% 5_2.txt"
)
endlocal
```

In the directory of this batch file is the text file `Length Test Input.txt` which has six lines ending all with carriage return and line-feed. The six lines are:

```
Line 1 - 8184 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abc
Line 2 - 8186 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcde
Line 3 - 8189 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcdefgh
Line 4 - 8190 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcdefghi
Line 5 - 8191 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcdefghij
Line 6 - 8192 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcdefghijk
```

`...` is used here as a placeholder for 814 repetitions of `0123456789`.

The execution of this batch file produces ten files.

1. `Length Test Output 1_1.txt` and `Length Test Output 1_2.txt` contain:

   ```
   Line 1 - 8184 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abc
   Line 1 - 8184 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abc
   ```
2. `Length Test Output 2_1.txt` and `Length Test Output 2_2.txt` contain:

   ```
   Line 1 - 8184 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abc
   Line 1 - 8184 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abc
   Line 2 - 8186 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcde
   Line 2 - 8186 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcde
   ```
3. `Length Test Output 3_1.txt` and `Length Test Output 3_2.txt` contain:

   ```
   Line 1 - 8184 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abc
   Line 1 - 8184 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abc
   Line 2 - 8186 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcde
   Line 2 - 8186 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcde
   Line 3 - 8189 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcdefgh
   Line 3 - 8189 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcdefgh
   ```
4. `Length Test Output 4_1.txt` and `Length Test Output 4_2.txt` contain:

   ```
   Line 1 - 8184 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abc
   Line 2 - 8186 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcde
   Line 3 - 8189 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcdefgh
   ```
5. `Length Test Output 5_1.txt` and `Length Test Output 5_2.txt` contain:

   ```
   Line 1 - 8184 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abc
   Line 2 - 8186 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcde
   Line 3 - 8189 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcdefgh
   Line 4 - 8190 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcdefghi
   Line 5 - 8191 chars: 0123456789...0123456789abcdefghij
   ```

Conclusion:

1. The sixth line with 8192 characters is too long for being processed at all by the Windows command processor.
2. It does not make a difference for the contents of the created files if everything output with **ECHO** inside a **FOR** loop is first captured by `cmd.exe` and then written into a file (`*_1.txt` files) or each output is directly written into a file (`*_2.txt` files) on processing small file(s).
3. The output of a line with command **ECHO** with more than 8191 characters fails as demonstrated by `echo(!L! !L!`. The two created output files `Length Test Output 4_1.txt` and `Length Test Output 4_2.txt` contain only the lines output with `echo(%%I` in the two loops.
4. A **FOR** loop with command **SET** on which the argument string to process by **SET** has more than 8191 characters results in an exit of the loop before executing any command in body of the loop. I am quite sure that this behavior of the Windows command processor is definitely not expected by the vast majority of batch file programmers.

The batch file `LengthTest.cmd` produces the same ten files on Windows XP SP3, Windows 7 SP1 and Windows 10 1909.

Comment: Nitpicking: The total length of a line can be much longer than 8192 bytes. A line with a set command can be around 16000 bytes long, because the variable name can be 8184 characters and the content 8191 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0

For /f %%a in (A.txt) do (
set /a count=!count!+1
set A!count!=%%a
)
set count=0
For /f %%b in (B.txt) do (
set /a count=!count!+1
set B!count!=%%b
)
set recount=0
:loop
recount=%recount%+1
echo %A!recount!% %B!recount!%
if %recount% gtr %count% goto :end
goto :recount
:end
pause
exit
```

Hope this helped,

Yours Mona

**Note :** If there are more lines in `A.txt` then it will ignore them. If there are less, then it will show `[blank] [line from B.txt]`

Answer (score 0):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed "s#.*#s/.*/& \&/g;n#" A.txt|sed -f - B.txt
```

---

```
>sed "s#.*#s/.*/& \&/g;n#" A.txt|sed -f - B.txt
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
```