# How to split text files by lines using CMD prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd

I remember there used to be a way to split txt files by line in cmd prompt.  I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Anyone have any help?

Thanks!

Comment: See `Help for` especially the `/f` variant.

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `for /?` to get output the help for command __FOR__. Any internal command of Windows command processor `cmd.exe` as well as most external commands which are console applications in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` can be started with parameter `/?` in a command prompt window to get output the help for the command/application. There are thousands of posts on Stack Overflow using `for /F`, see for example [Print contents of txt file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576615/). Run just `help` to see a list of commands with brief description.

Answer (score -1):

`for /F "tokens=*" %i in (filename.txt) do @echo %i`

Replace `filename.txt` with your filename, and replace `@echo %i` with the command you want.

Source: [How do you loop through each line in a text file using a windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file)

Note: From my brief testing this works in with the standard windows command prompt (cmd), but not with PowerShell.