# How to read a text file line by line and modify every line using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Let's say there's a text file that contains:

```
L1
L2
L3
```

I want to have a batch file that will read each line from that file, and then make them into variables. For example, these will be the variables:

```
line1 = L1
line2 = L2
line3 = L3
```

How can this be done with a batch file?

Comment: Maybe you got the wrong idea... StackOverflow isn't a free coding service! Please take a look at [ask] and offer a [mcve] of what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows command processor is designed for running commands and applications. It is not designed for editing text files. Really every scripting or programming language would be better for this task than a batch file executed by Windows command processor `cmd.exe`.

For your simple text file example with using a [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) with one byte per character or [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) a simple batch file can be used:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "LineNumber=0"
del "%TEMP%\TextFile.tmp" 2>nul

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("TextFile.txt") do (
    set /A LineNumber+=1
    echo line!LineNumber! = %%I
) >>"%TEMP%\TextFile.tmp"

if exist "%TEMP%\TextFile.tmp" move /Y "%TEMP%\TextFile.tmp" "TextFile.txt"
if errorlevel 1 del "%TEMP%\TextFile.tmp"
endlocal
```

But this batch file fails to process a line correct which

- does not contain any character (empty line),
- starts with a semicolon `;`,
- contains one or more exclamation marks `!`.

A better but slower batch file would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "LineNumber=0"
del "%TEMP%\TextFile.tmp" 2>nul

for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^" "TextFile.txt" 2^>nul') do (
    set "Line=%%A"
    set /A LineNumber+=1
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo line!LineNumber! = !Line:*:=!
    endlocal
) >>"%TEMP%\TextFile.tmp"

if exist "%TEMP%\TextFile.tmp" move /Y "%TEMP%\TextFile.tmp" "TextFile.txt"
if errorlevel 1 del "%TEMP%\TextFile.tmp"
endlocal
```

See my answer on [How to read and print contents of text file line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579256/3074564) why the **FOR** loop is much more complex to process text files better.

A text file with [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) or [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) character encoding cannot be processed with those two batch files.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).